# Java / bukkit: Run "For" method 1 time in runnable?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

so I have this code:

```
                           ProtectedRegion region = WGBukkit.getRegionManager(p.getWorld()).getRegion("afk1mine");
                       Vector max = region.getMaximumPoint();
                       Vector min = region.getMinimumPoint();
                           for (int i = min.getBlockX(); i <= max.getBlockX();i++) {
                                 for (int j = min.getBlockY(); j <= max.getBlockY(); j++) {
                                   for (int k = min.getBlockZ(); k <= max.getBlockZ();k++) {
                                     final Block kasamas = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("paradise").getBlockAt(i,j,k);
                                         //Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(new BlockBreakEvent(kasamas, p));
                                         p.sendMessage(" kitas: " + kasamas); 
                                   }
                                 }
                               }
```

And i do want to send the message only for the first block, then repeat the runnable in 1 second and send the message for the second block etc.

Comment: Construct the entire message in your loop(s), then send it once (after the loop)?

Comment: This question is ambiguous. Do you only want to send the message for the first block? If so, you can set a boolean flag or just retrieve the first block before entering the loop and send that.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Yes, i do want to send the message only for the first block, then repeat the runnable in 1 second and send the message for the second block etc. Thanks!

Comment: @RokasŠčesnavičius **Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48129882/edit)**  your question.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch, done it.

Comment: What is 'the runnable'? It seems like you might want a [`BukkitRunnable`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html) that runs every 20 ticks which increments the coordinates each time it's run and then sends the message for that block.

Comment: @bcsb1001 That's what i am doing, but since the coordinates is in "for" it sends the message like 1000 times every second, and i need to do it only 1 time per BukkitRunnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment the coordinates *in the `BukkitRunnable`*. Something like this would work, although I'll admit it's not very nice to look at.

```
BukkitRunnable sendMessage = new BukkitRunnable() {
    final int minI = min.getBlockX(), minJ = min.getBlockY(), minK = min.getBlockZ();
    final int maxI = max.getBlockX(), maxJ = max.getBlockY(), maxK = max.getBlockZ();
    int i = minI, j = minJ, k = minK;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Block kasamas = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("paradise").getBlockAt(i, j, k);
        p.sendMessage(" kitas: " + kasamas);
        if (k > maxK) {
            if (j > maxJ) {
                if (i > maxI) {
                    cancel();
                } else {
                    i++;
                    j = minJ;
                    k = minK;
                }
            } else {
                j++;
                k = minK;
            }
        } else {
            k++;
        }
    }
};
sendMessage.runTaskTimer(plugin, 0, 20);
```

This assumes that `p` is [effectively final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4); otherwise, you may need to create an effectively final variable capturing it. Replace `plugin` with an instance of your plugin class.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! Thanks, this did really help me!